# List items inside php

Tags: php, html, list

So i have this in html

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="stuff.html">Stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="other.html">Other stuff</a></li>
</ul>
```

And i want to add this php code in the list:

```
<?php 
  ...
    elseif($_SESSION['logged']==false) 
        echo '<a href="registerform.html">Login</a></li>';
        echo '<a href="registerform.html">Register</a></li>';
 ?>
```

But instead of displaying 2 separate list items, one with Login and one with Register i only get one with those two links.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed starting `li` tags and brackets.

do this:

```
<?php 
  ...
    elseif($_SESSION['logged']==false) {
        echo '<li><a href="registerform.html">Login</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="registerform.html">Register</a></li>';
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$_SESSION['logged']` is going to be *not set* or *false* then use empty(), also your missed you opening `li` tags:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="stuff.html">Stuff</a></li>
    <li><a href="other.html">Other stuff</a></li>
    <?php if(empty($_SESSION['logged'])): ?>
    <li><a href="registerform.html">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="registerform.html">Register</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Just wondering if `<?php if(empty($_SESSION['logged'])): ?>` could be `<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['logged'])): ?>` ?

Comment: Or that way, as long as its checked before using, he may check further up who really knows, i recon the OP's done a runner ;p

Comment: LOL, yeah I'm thinking that also. Many (newbies/ rep `1`) do `post & run` and expect a "magical fix-all answer" when coming back from "school".

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotteh curly bracket `{` and `li`

```
<?php 
  ...
    elseif($_SESSION['logged']==false) {
        echo '<li><a href="registerform.html">Login</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="registerform.html">Register</a></li>';
    }
 ?>
```